# sshd not listening on port 22 after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sshd

Ever since I updated to the latest Ubuntu release (18.04) I am unable to ssh into the machine until I walk over to the console and wake up the machine by hitting a key on the keyboard or moving the mouse. The machine is not asleep or hibernating, because I get a response back from ping when it's in this state. Obviously this is an undesirable state of affairs, as it makes me very reluctant to install updates which require reboots, even if they involve security patches, if I'm not physically located where the Ubuntu box is. What could be going on?

Comment: Hmh, you could be wrong about the sleep state, network adapters might still respond even if the machine itself is sleeping. E.g. WOL (WakeonLAN) uses exactly this method to wake up a server remotely. If I were you I'd check BIOS and Power settings in Ubuntu and disable them, then recheck the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I should have mentioned in the original problem description that I had checked the power settings in Ubuntu and confirmed that sleeping/hibernating is turned off (and I probably would have if I had realized that ping responses might not mean what I thought they did). Can an Ubuntu upgrade actually modify the BIOS settings?

Comment: I think it can only trigger events which are allowed by the bios. if its deactivated in bios, no chance that the os can override it, afaik, never heard of it and would be a terrible security issue.

Comment: try the following to test this... open a ssh shell and make sure to send tcp_keep_alive packages from the cliuent to the server so that the connection never closes. Leave the terminal open for (I dunno lets say) 12 hours and see if the terminal is still alive and connected to the server. If it really doesn't go asleep, the connection should still be open even after this period. Just a suggestion to test and norrow down the problem.

Comment: @s1mmel, you were right, the machine was going to sleep and it was the NIC which was responding to the ping requests. I "fixed" the problem by installing a fresh 18.04.

Comment: I'll write my answer, woulf be nice if you could upvote it... so ppl with the same problem can use the same method of testing this.

Comment: I will upvote it (because I appreciate that you took the time to try and help) but reluctantly (because we still don't know why the machine no longer sticks around to listen to port 22 after the upgrade). edit - I don't have enough points for my upvote to be visible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH Server stops working after reboot, caused by missing /var/run/sshd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109934/ssh-server-stops-working-after-reboot-caused-by-missing-var-run-sshd)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the server goes into sleep state. The ping to the server is not a solid prove. The card itself could be active while the server is in sleep state (e.g. WAkeOverLan uses this method to start sleeping machines in the morning, if configured).

To test this behavior you could simply open a ssh connection in a terminal from another machine and keep the connection open with keepalive packets, which can be set under /etc/ssh/ssh_config. Add the following lines...

```
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

After that the connection to the server should stay open all the time. If it does not, then most probably your server suspended into sleep state.